# Very basic OO: changing attribute of a method

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm certain this has been asked a million times, but it's difficult to search for something when you don't know the correct terminology :(

I'm attempting (again... I've *never* understood OO, since I got taught it very badly 8 years ago, and avoid it as much as possible, to the horror of every other programmer I know - my mind doesn't seem wired to get it, at all) to teach myself OO and PyQt simultaneously.

I don't even know if this is logically possible, but I've got a PyQt *action*, which is referred to by 2 different *things*; one of the arguments of the action is an Icon.  When the action called by one of those *things*, I'd like to change the icon; code snippet:

```
self.menu()
self.toolbar()
self.actions()

def menu(self):
  self.fileMenu = QtGui.QMenu("&File", self)
  self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitAct)

def toolbar(self):
  self.toolbar = self.addToolBar("Exit")
  self.toolbar.addAction(self.exitAct)

def actions(self):
  self.exitIcon = QtGui.QIcon('exit.png')
  self.exitAct = QtGui.QAction(self.exitIcon, "&Exit", self, triggered=self.close)
```

In the toolbar, I'd like a different icon (`exitdoor.png`). The documentation for `QtIcon` has an `addFile` method, so I tried:

```
self.toolbar.addAction(self.exitAct)
self.exitIcon.addFile("exitdoor.png")
```

but this didn't work, with the error ("'QToolBar' object has no attribute 'addFile'"), and

```
self.exitAct.addFile("exitdoor.png")
```

with the error 'QAction' object has no attribute 'addFile' (I do understand why this doesn't work and what the error means).

What's my stupid mistake?! (Apart from the mistake of putting myself through the pain of continuing to try and learn OO...)

Comment: If you can, I'd suggest you try PySide. My experience with both has led to me preferring PySide, though PyQt4 can be improved by using the v2 APIs for QString, Slot, etc. (They've got basically the same API, but PySide is licensed more liberally while PyQt4 has to keep various things backwards-compatible, which has made PySide more nimble in its development.)

Comment: Your separating of things into methods (`menu`, `toolbar`, `actions`) doesn't make sense. They need to be run all together and only once, so they should be in one method.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan hmm.. that's an interesting comment; I'd been using an image viewer I'd found online to help me: http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.7.2/examples/widgets/imageviewer.py - that's how they split things up, so was just following their example

Comment: `'QToolBar' object has no attribute 'addFile'` hence in your code you have `self.toolbar.addFile` instead of `self.exitIcon.addFile` or you assign a toolbar object to `exitIcon` instead of a `QIcon`.
Next time please provide a minimal *working* example(i.e. that can be copy pasted and obtain the results you are seeing) plus *full traceback* of the errors.

Comment: @Bakuriu - sorry, I don't really follow what you're suggesting.  I'd gathered that `self.toolbar` would of the wrong type, which is why I tried `self.exitIcon.addFile`

Comment: As I said you should show *all* the code relevant to your problem. So, first of all track down what's the minimum subset of code that shows that error and then post all what you found. Otherwise we cannot do much more than an horoscope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to some much cleverer people than me, the short answer is that what I was trying to do is seemingly impossible.  Once an `action` has been defined, it is not possible to change any attribute of it.

At the moment, my knowledge of python isn't great enough to understand exactly why this is (or how I could  have realised this from the docs), but it seems that when an action is defined, it is effectively a blackbox stored in memory, and other objects can only use, and not modify, the blackbox.

Further comments still welcome!

Answer (score 1):

> 'QToolBar' object has no attribute 'addFile'

Hmm, since you called addFile on self.exitIcon, it looks like you have the wrong kind of object in the self.exitIcon variable. It seems you want it to be a QtGui.QIcon type, but instead it's a QToolBar type.

You should look at where you are making assignments to self.exitIcon.

In this case, trying to learn object-oriented programming through Python is not the easiest way. Python is a fine object-oriented language, but it does not catch your errors as immediately as other languages. When you get an error like the above, the mistake was not in that line of code, but rather in a line of code that ran a while ago. Other languages would catch the mistake even before you run your program, and point you directly at the line you need to fix. It might be worthwhile for you to practice a little basic Java to get trained in OOP by a strict teacher before you go off into the wilds of Python.

Comment: This doesn't have *anything* to do with OOP. You are pointing out differences between statically and dynamically typed languages. I'd also argue that learning OOP is not related to learning a language and one can write non-OOP or bad-OOP code in Java quite easily(and you often see code like that). The educational advantage of "enforcing OOP design" in the language is highly arguable.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to do with OOP in particular. It has to do with understanding the root cause of *any* programming mistake being easier in a statically-typed language (though I've had experiences with C compilers that give incredibly unhelpful messages even for compile-time errors).

Comment: Educational advantage in general is probably highly arguable, but the struggling student won't likely bother to follow the arguments. They will just take the advice or leave it, and be successful following it or not. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PyQt and only a beginner with Python, but I have quite a bit of experience with other OO languages (primarily C++ and Java). It looks like you need to determine what kind of object is stored in the fields `exitIcon` and `exitAct`. From there, you need to find out what attributes these objects have and find the one which you can change to get the behavior you want.

**More thoughts:**

Somewhere between the execution of `self.exitIcon = QtGui.QIcon('exit.png')` and `self.exitIcon.addFile("exitdoor.png")` `self.exitIcon` is changed to refer to a `QToolBar`. I suggest that you start sprinkling your code with `print` statements so you can trace the execution of your code and find out how this variable was changed.

Comment: Yes - what you say makes sense! I don't understand how `self.exitIcon` can be of type `QToolBar` when it's being called as a `QIcon`

Comment: @ChrisW What is the type of `self` in this context? And, probably more importantly, where is `exitIcon` initialized?

Comment: I'm going to show my naïvety here and admit that I don't really understand what type `self` is or how it's determined.  My class is `class testProg(QtGui.QMainWindow):` - so is `self` `QMainWindow`? `exitIcon` is only initialised how I've shown in my question

Comment: @chris If the code you have given is inside a method in the `testProg` class, then the type of `self` is `testProg`. For future reference, it will help if you add the `class xxx` line to indicate what class contains the methods you post in a question. The next thing to look at is where is the line `self.exitIcon.addFile("exitdoor.png")`? Is this in another method of `testProg`?